# update or insert in siddhi file to ignore unavailable fields rather than updating all the fields

Tags: siddhi

I have a siddhi file to read from kafka topic and write to database.

```
@store(type='rdbms' , datasource='WSO2_CLUSTER',table.name='sample_table')
define table sample_table(col1 string, col2 string, corr_id string);


from kafkaInputMetricCorr
select col1, col2, corr_id
update or insert into sample_table 
on sample_table.corr_id == corr_id;
```

When I use this "update or insert" feature, it updates all the fields (col1, col2, corr_id) even though the field is not available in the Kafka event. When the kafka message has "col1 and corr_id", I want only col1 and corr_id to be updated. What happens right now is, it is updating the col2 to be null. I even tried to change to

```
select *
```

hoping that only the fields available in Kafka event will be updated. But its not working. Please help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use set clause if you do not want to update all fields, https://siddhi.io/en/v5.1/docs/query-guide/#update-or-insert

```
from kafkaInputMetricCorr
select col1, col2, corr_id
update or insert into sample_table 
set sample_table.col1 = col1, sample_table.corr_id = corr_id
on sample_table.corr_id == corr_id;
```